# Dnytopo constant at 6 looks really bad, not like video I am following (blender 2.8)

Tags: dynamic-topology

So found this 'beginner' tutorial on blender 2.8 that makes this nifty low poly scene.  3 minutes in I am like 'um not getting the same thing'.  Tried it several times and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong when going into sculpt mode from relative to constant at a resolution of 6.  It looks nothing like the video which I follow as far as I can tell to a T...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lj643VmTsg

and my result:

[image]

It is so course and nothing like what he gets about 3.5 minutes in?

Comment: What size and subdivision of icosphere did you start with? Still only see that he turns on dyntopo, sets it to constant detail and sets the scale to 6 and uses a simple draw brush.

Comment: I did what he did, added the icosphere, made it from 2 to 3 subdivisions, then scaled it by 10, which was accomplished by hitting S then typing 10.

Comment: Maybe try applying scale and rotation with ctrl-A...

Comment: couldn't figure out the rotation portion,  like what rotation would I give it?  I did notice it didn't look like in the video but it also was't all jankey if instead of scaling i increased the radius to 10m (not sure if the units are the same) or what the difference is in creating the sphere and increasing the radius vs scaling it with S

Comment: I just mean to apply scale and rotation under object so that the tools behave properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this same issue coming into the tutorial, and one of the things I did was check the comments and a user with the name Daium said to try setting the resolution to 60. I think it is because this person in the tutorial had a different scale with numbers. anyway I tried it and it worked.